# Using astropy to convert pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, astropy

I have a `pandas` dataframe that includes the columns `_RA2000` and `_DEJ2000`, thus:

```
_RAJ2000,_DEJ2000,RA_ICRS,DE_ICRS,mode,q_mode,class,SDSS12,m_SDSS12,ObsDate,Q,umag,e_umag,gmag,e_gmag,rmag,e_rmag,imag,e_imag,zmag,e_zmag,zsp,zph,e_zph,<zph>
02 59 43.85208,+00 14 50.0532,44.932717,0.247237,1,+,6,J025943.85+001450.0,*,2004.7267,3,25.252,0.709,24.427,0.377,22.923,0.186,22.844,0.255,22.173,0.505,,,,
02 59 43.18896,+00 14 49.9776,44.929954,0.247216,1,+,3,J025943.18+001449.9,,2004.7267,3,25.77,0.713,23.41,0.267,22.467,0.183,21.612,0.132,20.905,0.301,,0.5976,0.1462,0.5771
02 59 45.92184,+00 15 09.6372,44.941341,0.252677,1,+,3,J025945.92+001509.6,,2004.7267,3,23.707,1.067,22.886,0.219,21.501,0.105,21.026,0.104,20.984,0.423,,0.423,0.0924,0.4151
02 59 44.95968,+00 15 11.7252,44.937332,0.253257,1,+,3,J025944.95+001511.7,,2004.7267,3,22.729,0.546,24.475,0.791,21.847,0.152,21.244,0.137,21.931,0.96,,0.4073,0.1245,0.4036
02 59 42.50736,+00 15 01.6416,44.927114,0.250456,1,,3,J025942.50+001501.6,*,2004.7267,3,22.529,0.467,22.705,0.198,22.117,0.203,21.279,0.139,20.905,0.418,,0.7674,0.0744,0.7239
02 59 42.88320,+00 15 01.8144,44.92868,0.250504,1,,3,J025942.88+001501.8,*,2004.7267,3,24.755,0.864,23.219,0.168,22.533,0.14,22.161,0.152,22.508,0.602,,0.3329,0.1434,0.2613
02 59 41.84880,+00 15 05.7924,44.92437,0.251609,1,+,3,J025941.84+001505.7,*,2004.7267,3,22.849,0.377,23.707,0.279,22.378,0.141,21.274,0.082,20.76,0.221,,0.6223,0.0731,0.6115
02 59 46.54512,+00 15 10.8972,44.943938,0.253027,1,+,3,J025946.54+001510.8,*,2004.7267,3,22.34,0.372,21.589,0.074,20.139,0.033,19.577,0.031,19.066,0.081,,0.4006,0.0569,0.4019
02 59 45.76656,+00 15 34.6932,44.940694,0.259637,1,,3,J025945.76+001534.6,,2004.7267,3,25.362,0.977,22.829,0.169,22.873,0.266,23.286,0.543,21.734,0.601,,0.5175,0.1433,0.3604
```

and I'd like to convert them to degrees, as they appear in the `RAJ2000` and `DEJ2000` columns. I should be able to do it with `astropy`, but if I try the first one:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
c = SkyCoord('23 58 36.30073', 'icrs', unit=(u.hourangle))
```

I get

```
ValueError: Invalid character at col 0 in angle 'icrs'
```

So my questions are:

- why is the string I've inputted causing the error, and
- how can I apply `SkyCoord` to the `pandas` columns?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your data, instead print the dataframe `print(df)` and post the output as text. This makes it easier to reproduce the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the conversion for both coords simultaneously and supply the frame as a keyword argument:

```
import pandas as pd
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

df = pd.DataFrame({'_RAJ2000': ['23 58 36.30073 ',  '23 58 19.66200 ',  '23 58 17.43747 ',  '23 58 10.18153 ',  
                                '23 57 42.51840 ',  '23 56 32.18853 ',  '23 56 30.99313 ',  '23 56 06.29927 ',
                                '23 55 33.67007 ',  '23 55 14.54907 ',  '23 54 19.62527 ',  '23 52 46.54273 ',
                                '23 52 02.17560 ',  '23 51 50.76387 '],
                   '_DEJ2000': ['+03 07 21.9650',  '+14 36 42.0370',  '+15 16 40.3390',  '+11 20 06.6370',
                                '+06 19 41.0660',  '+07 30 53.1500',  '+07 21 08.8880',  '+11 24 22.3520',
                                '+04 37 36.1520',  '+10 59 36.1680',  '+08 15 14.7020',  '+01 57 15.8870',
                                '+02 36 10.4110',  '+03 53 50.8780']})

df = pd.concat(
    (df, SkyCoord(df._RAJ2000, df._DEJ2000, frame='icrs', unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)).to_table().to_pandas()),
    axis=1).rename(columns={'ra': 'RAJ2000', 'dec': 'DEJ2000'})
```

Result:

```
           _RAJ2000        _DEJ2000     RAJ2000    DEJ2000
0   23 58 36.30073   +03 07 21.9650  359.651253   3.122768
1   23 58 19.66200   +14 36 42.0370  359.581925  14.611677
2   23 58 17.43747   +15 16 40.3390  359.572656  15.277872
3   23 58 10.18153   +11 20 06.6370  359.542423  11.335177
4   23 57 42.51840   +06 19 41.0660  359.427160   6.328074
5   23 56 32.18853   +07 30 53.1500  359.134119   7.514764
6   23 56 30.99313   +07 21 08.8880  359.129138   7.352469
7   23 56 06.29927   +11 24 22.3520  359.026247  11.406209
8   23 55 33.67007   +04 37 36.1520  358.890292   4.626709
9   23 55 14.54907   +10 59 36.1680  358.810621  10.993380
10  23 54 19.62527   +08 15 14.7020  358.581772   8.254084
11  23 52 46.54273   +01 57 15.8870  358.193928   1.954413
12  23 52 02.17560   +02 36 10.4110  358.009065   2.602892
13  23 51 50.76387   +03 53 50.8780  357.961516   3.897466
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'SkyCoord' object has no attribute 'to_table'

Comment: `to_table` was introduced in version 5.0, see last item [here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/changelog.html#id41). Can you update your astropy installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the `Angle` class if you just want to use astropy to parse the coordinate strings

```
>>> from astropy.coordinates import Angle
>>> Angle(['23 58 36.30073 ',  '23 58 19.66200 '], unit='hourangle').to_value('deg')
array([359.65125304, 359.581925  ])

>>> Angle(['+03 07 21.9650',  '+14 36 42.0370'], unit='deg').to_value('deg')
array([ 3.12276806, 14.61167694])
```